# Mongoose: findByIdAndUpdate doesn't update the document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to **increment voteCount by 1** when user select a particular option. the data looks like this -

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "58f2ef61af2c5c068c2f1d7a"
    },        
    "pollName": "Who is your favourite cricketer ?",        
    "options": [
        {
            "name": "Dhoni",
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "58f2ef61af2c5c068c2f1d7d"
            },
            "voteCount": 10
        },
        {
            "name": "Kohli",
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "58f2ef61af2c5c068c2f1d7c"
            },
            "voteCount": 6
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0
}
```

**I tried this -**

```
// req.body.votedFor is coming fine.
PollModel.findByIdAndUpdate(req.session.pollId, {$inc: { options: {name: req.body.votedFor, voteCount : 1 } }}, {new: true}, function(err, doc){
    if(err){
        console.log("Something wrong when updating data! "+err);
    }
    console.log(doc);
  });
```

It is **does not update the voteCount** and I am getting this message -

**Something wrong when updating data! MongoError: Cannot increment with non-numeric argument: {options: { voteCount: 1, name: "Dhoni" }}**
**undefined**

where am i doing wrong ? **Kindly help**.

Comment: Do you try to read an error param from callback function?  I think it'll help you to determine a problem.

Comment: @Dmitry problem is  in { $inc...}. but how to go till the option name ? please guide.

Comment: @RiyaSaxena getting error, unexpected identifier $inc:

Comment: @RiyaSaxena I tried to put '{' before $inc. but got error - unexpected token { . please guide.

Comment: if(req.body.votedFor && req.body.votedFor!='')
 setObj['options.name'] = req.body.votedFor;
qobj['options.voteCount']=1;
var updateObj = {};
updateObj['$set'] = setObj;
updateObj['$inc'] = qobj;
PollModel.findByIdAndUpdate({"_id":req.session.pollId},updateObj, {new: true}, function(err, doc){
 if(err){
  console.log("Something wrong when updating data! "+err);
 }
 console.log(doc);
});

Comment: Try this `PollModel.findOneAndUpdate({_id:mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.session.pollId), "options.name": req.body.votedFor},{$inc:{"options.$.voteCount":1} }, {new: true}, function(err, doc){     if(err){         console.log("Something wrong when updating data! "+err);     }     console.log(doc);   });` More info here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/

Comment: @Veeram thank you so much. A small modification i did in id - "_id":req.session.pollId. it worked. :)

Comment: @Veeram could you please explain a little bit this- "options.$.voteCount"

Comment: You are welcome. `options.name` in the query part is used to locate the index of `options` array followed by $ placeholder which replaces the value with array index to increment the `voteCount` for array element.

Comment: @Veeram got it. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated a little bit @Veeram Solution. this is the working code -

```
PollModel.findOneAndUpdate({"_id":req.session.pollId, "options.name": req.body.votedFor}, {$inc:{"options.$.voteCount":1} }, {new: true}, function(err, doc){
    if(err){
        console.log("Something wrong when updating data! "+err);
    }
    console.log(doc);
    res.send(doc);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(req.body.votedFor && req.body.votedFor!='')
    setObj['options.name'] = req.body.votedFor;
qobj['options.voteCount']=1;
var updateObj = {};
updateObj['$set'] = setObj;
updateObj['$inc'] = qobj;
PollModel.findByIdAndUpdate({"_id":req.session.pollId},updateObj, {new: true}, function(err, doc){
    if(err){
        console.log("Something wrong when updating data! "+err);
}
console.log(doc);
```

});

Comment: got this error - MongoError: cannot use the part (options of options.name) to traverse the element